# Whats the difference between create blob and create block blob action in Azure logic apps?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

Need clarity on when to use Create blob and create block blob actions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create blob -- This operation uploads a blob to Azure Blob Storage.
- Create block blob -- This operation uploads a **block** blob to Azure Blob Storage.

Blob contains block blob, page blob and append blob.
Refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblob/#actions).

Comment: Just curious, can I create a page or append blob using "Create blob" action? If it creates only block blob then why do we have these two separate actions?

Comment: You need to add logic in automated system to check whether it write completely. Then trigger the create blob action.

Comment: The block blob upload large blobs efficiently. While you issue is blob content need await write.  Change to create block blob is useless.

Comment: As my test, when you not write completely,  the blob is not be created. So please check whether your file has content in it.